# MongoDB: WriteCommandError - issue with authentication

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm running mongo container and I am not able to run any commands inside. When I run my app - Java throws this Exception:

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server 10.0.75.1:27018. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }

When I go inside the container and try to create a user/insert anything it fails with:

```
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: "myUserAdmin",
...     pwd: "abc123",
...     roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
...   }
... )
```

2020-03-13T02:23:06.847+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication :

_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13

DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1370:11

$show dbs - indicates no databases there.

Though when I use compass, I can easily connect to mongo and I am able to see default dbs there

**I would appreciate any advise! Thank you!**

Here is my .yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:

   database-mongodb:
      image: mongo:4.2.3-bionic
      ports:
        - 27018:27017
      networks:
         - music-library-network
      environment:
         MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
         MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password123

   core-app:
      image: bohdan57/alpine-jdk11-sqlite
      ports:
        - 80:8080
      networks:
         - music-library-network
      depends_on:
         - database-mongodb

networks:
   music-library-network:
```

Comment: When you are connected inside the container, try running `db.getSiblingDB("admin").auth("root","password123")`

Comment: That helped! My MongoClientURI looked like: "mongodb://" + mongoUser + ":" + mongoPassword + "@" + ip + ":" + externalPort + "/" + __myDBName__;   I changed the bold part to admin database, configured MongoClient to work using that connection and that worked! From my undertanding it is vital to establish connection with MongoServer using admin db, not the db ur gonna use after. Thank you Joe!

Comment: There is an [authenticationDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/index.html#cmdoption-mongo-authenticationdatabase) option to allow you to authenticate to one database while connecting to another